# How can I return a tuple of a vector and a reference to a value inside the vector?

Tags: rust, lifetime

The following code could theoretically work, because the reference returned in the tuple points to a location on the heap:

```
fn foo<'a>() -> (Vec<u32>, &'a u32){
    let v=vec![1];
    (v, v.get(0).unwrap())
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `v`
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     (v, v.get(0).unwrap())
   |     ^^^^--------^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |   |
   |     |   `v` is borrowed here
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Why? The pointer is still valid after the function returns. Is the compiler not smart enough to see this? Or is there another reason this doesn't work?
And is there another way to return a structure like this? Without `Rc` or `Arc`?

Comment: What connects the `Vec` and the reference after the function returns? For example, the caller could drop the `Vec` then access the reference.

Comment: This makes sense. But is there a way to tell the compiler the relation of their lifetimes?

Comment: No (except crates such as `ouroboros`). So this can be considered a limitation of the language, or the compiler. Rust indeed makes it hard to create self-referential structs, even safe ones. The [`owning_ref`](https://docs.rs/owning_ref) crate aims to handle that case where the data is on the heap and therefore they should be safe, but it is known to be unsound. Self-referential structs are hard. There is also the newer [`yoke`](https://docs.rs/yoke) crate.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I know fully understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I didn't know about `Yoke`  (by the Unicode.org team, btw). Let me add an example with it to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This will never work as is: `Vec::get()` borrows the vector, and then you are trying to move it out of the function, but you cannot move a borrowed vector.

Also the `'a` generic is to be specified by the caller of the function, not to be defined by the implementation, as is any other generic parameter. But that does not apply here, there is no valid lifetime for that `'a`.

For simple cases such as this, I would just return the index of the value `(Vec<u32>, usize)`.

For more complex cases you can use `Rc/Arc` for the inner values of the vector and clone it before returning:

```rust
fn foo() -> (Vec<Rc<u32>>, Rc<u32>){
    let v=vec![Rc::new(1)];
    let r = Rc::clone(&v[0]);
    (v, r)
}
```

If the `Rc` inside the `Vec` is not desired, you could create a self-referential struct and return that. Using the `ouroboros` crate that would be something like:

```rust
use ouroboros::self_referencing;

#[self_referencing]
struct VecAndRef {
    pub data: Vec<u32>,
    #[borrows(data)]
    pub ref0: &'this u32,
}

fn foo() -> VecAndRef {
    let v=vec![1];

    VecAndRefBuilder {
        data: v,
        ref0_builder: |data| data.get(0).unwrap(),
    }.build()
}

fn test() {
    let f = foo();
    println!("{:?}", f.borrow_data());
    println!("{}", f.borrow_ref0());
}
```

Or using the `yoke` crate, suggested by Chayim Friedman in a comment:

```rust
use yoke::Yoke;

fn foo() -> Yoke<&'static u32, Vec<u32>> {
    let v = vec![1];
    Yoke::attach_to_cart(v, |v| &v[0])
}


fn main() {
    let f = foo();
    println!("{:?}", f.backing_cart());
    println!("{}", f.get());
}
```

Comment: Hm. But when `foo` returns, then the borrowed vector is already returned, isn't it?
I mean this code
`fn foo<'a>() -> Vec<u32>{
    let v=vec![1];
    v.get(0);
    v
}`
works.

Comment: @Lukas: Your code works because the return value of `v.get(0)` is dropped immediately so when `v` is returned it is no longer borrowed. But that is not the case in the code from the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But doesn't `v.get(0).unwrap()` in `(v, v.get(0).unwrap())` drops the borrowed v before the tuple is returned? I mean the tuple contains no borrow of `v`. I rather think the problem is that the compiler is not sure whether the value referenced by `v.get(0).unwrap()` is still valid after the return.

Comment: When returning the reference it is not dropped, it is moved outside of the function. So the `v` is kept borrowed, but `v` is also moved, hence the error. The fact that you return a tuple with a reference inside instead of a plain reference changes nothing about that.